# How to make bootstrap tooltip remain visible till the link is clicked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a link which I am going to use as notification when a user has some new notification I am going to notify the user by showing a tooltip(twitter bootstrap tooltip). What I want to achieve is, that tooltip should remain visible till the user clicks the link. once the user clicks the link, the tooltip should destroy.
this is what I have till now, http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/QsYPv/

HTML

```
<p><a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="you have 2 notifications">Notification</a>.</p>​
```

JavaScript

```
$('p a').tooltip({placement: 'bottom'}).tooltip('show');​
```

What's happening there is, tooltip stays visible till you hover it, and takes its default behaviour (show on hover) once you hover it.

I hope I have given proper info and cleared what I want to do.

Comment: Try adding the option `trigger: 'manual'` when creating the tooltip if you're showing it using the API anyway.

Comment: @millimoose added that option, now it has lost its default behavior.

Comment: Solved with this line 
    $('p a').on('click',function(){$(this).tooltip('destroy');});

Comment: @vikasdevde You should post your full solution as an answer and accept it. For visitors.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/QsYPv/8/

Added the option "trigger"

```
$('p a').tooltip({placement: 'bottom',trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
```

then, with this line

```
$('p a').on('click',function(){$(this).tooltip('destroy');});
```

destroy tooltip on click.

Comment: this is what i was searching in google, now i got the answer. thankyou so much :)

Comment: This answer is no longer valid/working, 'show' is no longer an option for tooltip()

Comment: What version of BS @satnam several others also confirm this no longer works in latest version

Comment: Can you do this with pure JavaScript? I want to keep my tooltips always visible forever until the end of the world.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a variable to trigger off the mouseleave event to re-show the tooltip, and then as you said in your comment, just destroy the tooltip when clicked, so it doesn't show when you mouseover again:

```
var clickedNotify = false;
$('p a').tooltip({placement: 'bottom'}).tooltip('show');
$('p a').mouseleave(function() { if (!clickedNotify) { $('p a').tooltip({placement: 'bottom'}).tooltip('show'); } });
$('p a').click(function() { clickedNotify = true; $(this).tooltip('destroy'); });
```

This way, the tooltip is always shown, even after a mouseleave, until the link is clicked. After the link is clicked, the tooltip is destroyed, and still won't generate javascript errors on the page on mouseleave.

Answer (score 1):

For bootstap 5 you can use:

```
    // get all tooltips
    const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
    // loop trough tooltips
    const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => {
        const tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
        // make tooltips visible on load
        tooltip.show()
        // keep tooltips in view
        tooltipTriggerEl.addEventListener('hide.bs.tooltip', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
        })
        return tooltip
    })
```