# Boostrap tooltip interaction and automatic hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a text with wrapped  `<span>` sections:

```
<span id="id1">Text1 Text1 Text1</span><span id="id2">Text2 Text2 Text2</span><span id="id3">Text3 Text3 Text3</span>
```

This is a simplified example. In my use case, there is much more text and any given section might span one or more lines.

I am having event triggers attached to the span elements that highlight the respective text section on "mouseenter" and unhighlight on "mouseleave". Works fine.

In addition to the highlighting, I want to show a bootstrap tooltip, more or less also triggered by "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events. But the latter gets more complicated:

Problem: The tooltip contains some form elements and right now, the user isn't able to interact with these form elements because the tooltip is positioned above the span elements containing the text and the "mouseleave" event which currently calls $('#element').tooltip('hide') closes the tooltip before the user reaches it.

I did some research and found something comparable here [How to make bootstrap tooltip to remain visible till the link is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015432/how-to-make-bootstrap-tooltip-to-remain-visible-till-the-link-is-clicked), but in this scenario the tooltip stays open until the user clicks a link within the tooltip. In my scenario, the user does not necessarily has to interact with the tooltip. So there must be some kind of automatic hiding mechanism in place.

How could this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap Popover which can be trigger at hover as well because tooltip is generally use for displaying the messages.

**Here is the Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/vzzxrLtk/

One more important thing whenever you use HTML element in data-content like

`data-content='<div id="insideDiv"><input type="text"></input><button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></div>'>`

atrribute you should add one more attribute

`data-html="true"`

Comment: Tooltips can be triggered on hover as well. Anyway, your approach is based on timeout, giving the user a certain amount of time to reach the popover. Not yet decided if it#s the "best" approach.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to get the bounding box of a span using Element.getBoundingClientRect() method and save the properties.

Then use mousemove event on the upper container and check of event.clientX/event.clientY is beyond the bounding box. Once this is the case, close the currently visible tooltip.

Show the another tooltip mouseenter (span) and only if no other tooltip is shown.

After some fine tuning of the bounding box's frame, it works quite good.