# create a hover-tooltip which can be clicked in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am trying to create a hover-tooltip using Bootstrap UI. The tooltip should be visible when mouse is hovered on the button, the tooltip has a link which should be clickable. But the default popover and tooltip provided by Bootstrap UI, disappear when mouse comes out of it. 
I have searched a lot online, but couldn't find a solution. Some sites have given a solution using jQuery, but my requirement is in AngularJS. Many sites cite that we have to use $tooltipProvider, could you please tell me how to write a customEvent for 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' inside the controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015432/how-to-make-bootstrap-tooltip-to-remain-visible-till-the-link-is-clicked

Comment: That one doesn't use the angular tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this link,

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WojtekKruszewski/Zf3m7/22/light/

It has been achieved using jQuery, write a directive in AngularJS. You can integrate jQuery plugin in angularJS app, look at this site

https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for popover tooltip which is being stable and hide once it is accessed...Please see below working fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6rvjhbcb/)

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle infoIcon" data-toggle="popover" data-content='Lorem Ipsum<br/><a href="#"><span class="learnMore">Learn More</span></a>'></i>
```

JS:

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle infoIcon" data-toggle="popover" data-content='Lorem Ipsum<br/><a href="#"><span class="learnMore">Learn More</span></a>'></i>
```

Comment: The popover should disappear if mouse is not on the text or the popover. The fiddle you've written, the popover doesn't disappear at all.

Comment: It satisfies my requirement, but how do you manipulate it inside a controller?

Answer (score 0):

I made a sticky dropdown extension for dropdown. Here's my code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.stickyDropdownToggle', []).directive('stickyDropdownToggle', ['$document', '$location', function ($document, $location) {
    var openElement = null,
      closeMenu = angular.noop;
    return {
        restrict: 'CA',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('$location.path', function () { closeMenu(); });
            element.parent().bind("click", function (event) { if (event) { event.stopPropagation(); } });
            element.bind('click', function (event) {

                var elementWasOpen = (element === openElement);

                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();

                if (!!openElement) {
                    closeMenu();
                }

                if (!elementWasOpen && !element.hasClass('disabled') && !element.prop('disabled')) {
                    element.parent().addClass('open');
                    openElement = element;
                    closeMenu = function (event) {
                        if (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        $document.unbind('click', closeMenu);
                        element.parent().removeClass('open');
                        closeMenu = angular.noop;
                        openElement = null;
                    };
                    $document.bind('click', closeMenu);
                }
            });
        }
    };
} ]);
```

and to use it:

```
<button type="button" class="btn sticky-dropdown-toggle" ng-click="focusOnParticularElementInsideThePopup()"
                                        style="font-size: 1em">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>
                                </button>
```

Comment: i'm unable to get it working, can you please give me a link to fiddle or plnkr ?