# How to make bootstrap tooltip always visible in Pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, tooltip, bootstrap-5

Hi I was looking for solutions about having the tooltips of my page always visible and came accross the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015432/how-to-make-bootstrap-tooltip-remain-visible-till-the-link-is-clicked). However all the solutions provided to this is using JQuery.

Here is the code used to always show the tooltip which I want to convert to JS but I don't know how. I haven't found much documentation about this.

```
$('p a').tooltip({placement: 'bottom',trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
```

The JQuery code above seems to be working okay. You can test it [here (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip&stacked=h).

And Here is my HTML:

```
<span class="span-navigator-above-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Tooltip on top" data-placement="top" style="z-index: 3;">

    <div data-title="Event Information" id="progress-bar-indicator-button-1" class="progress-step progress-step-active"></div>
</span>
```

---

UPDATE 1:

As per my comment on coll's answer

```
in a loop: {
   //Indicator Progress Span (above bullet with text) 
   span = document.createElement("span");
   span.className = "indicator-tooltip-target";
   span.style.zIndex = "3";
   span.setAttribute("data-toggle","tooltip");
   span.setAttribute("data-original-title", "test");
}

later in the code in another loop: {
   let tooltips_target = document.getElementsByClassName("indicator-tooltip-target");

   for(var i=0; i<tooltips_target.length; i++){
      let tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltips_target[i]);
      tooltip.show();
   }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you've updated your tags and don't explicitly state which your asking about:

In [Bootstrap 4's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#js), jquery is required for tooltips to function:

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
> Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript
> plugins.

In [Bootstrap 5's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#show), you can run the show command through vanilla JS with:

```
var myTooltipEl = document.getElementById('myTooltip')
var tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(myTooltipEl)
tooltip.show()
```

Comment: Hi @coll thanks for your answer. It seems to be always showing the tooltip. But I have noticed this creates an additional set of HTML placed at the top of the page. However I still want to be able to manipulate those new bootstrap tooltips as well as you can see from the image. I also provide an update of my code. What I want to figure out is how to add id or class to the new tooltip so that I can change the title attribute manually. Also do I have to call the update() function each time I change the title?

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou Create additional SO questions around these new questions

Comment: Here is my [new SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71327870/how-to-manage-dynamically-created-bootstrap-tooltip-with-vanilla-js)