# How to manage dynamically created bootstrap.Tooltip() with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip, bootstrap-5

Hi I'm working on a multi-page registration system and I want to provide a tooltip **(ALWAYS VISIBLE)** for each indicator as shown in my image bellow.

[image: screenshot 1]

HOWEVER:

- I have noticed that when I create my tooltips using the `<span>` with Javascript as shown below, it will only work with **hover** event.
- And when I create it with `new bootstrap.Tooltip()` it will work as intended as long as I call the `.show()` function as shown below in the code.

*(FYI, the first tooltip shown in the image is actually the `<span>` and I'm hovering the mouse. The `bootstrap.Tooltip()` has style `display: none` only for blue indicator. So both `<span>` and `bootstrap.Tooltip()` overlap in case of `display: block`)*

Something strange that I have also noticed is that when a tooltip is created via `newbootstrap.Tooltip()` a new `<div>` is created at the top of the page which will have the information of the `<span>` but will not take the id or className. It has it's own id which is random on every page reload (e.g. tooltip768493, tooltip714418, tooltip9188236)

What I'm trying to figure out is how to set a default `className` or `id` on each of the `bootstrap.Tooltip()` so that I can change their title dynamically as shown below:

- Blue - You are here
- Red - Missing or Invalid
- Green - Valid
- Grey - Optional

Here is how I created the tooltip targets:

```
   //in a for loop create 6 spans to hold tooltips:

   //Indicator Progress Span (above bullet with text) 
   span = document.createElement("span");
   span.className = "indicator-tooltip-target";
   span.style.zIndex = "3";
   span.setAttribute("data-toggle","tooltip");
   span.setAttribute("data-original-title", "test");
```

```
function show_tooltips(){
    let tooltips_target = document.getElementsByClassName("indicator-tooltip-target");
    for(var i=0; i<tooltips_target.length; i++){
        let tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltips_target[i]);
        tooltip.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `tooltip.title("[text]")` or setting `span.setAttribute("data-original-title", "test");` from an array of defined texts?

Comment: `tooltip.title("test")` is not a Function, and setting `span.Attribute()` will change the initial `<span>` NOT the `new bootstrap.Tooltip()`. And I cannot have a defined array of text to indicate title since its change according to user form control. I tried giving `span.setAttribute("customClass", "custom_class_span")` but didn't work. I want to call it from multiple areas in my code